# Custom system checks are getting ignored

Tags: django

Recently, I implemented a custom system check in our project. This check performs assertions based on our custom implementation of Django Rest Framework's model serializers. For debugging purposes on Visual Studio Code, I am using the debugpy package in conjunction with a Docker Compose setup. I followed this [article](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-vs-code/) to set it up.

After configuring the debugger, I noticed that my custom system checks were not functioning properly. Upon further troubleshooting, I realized that it was due to a configuration I made in the manage.py file as mentioned in the article.

In the [article](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-vs-code/#modify-managepy), they recommend adding the following code block to the manage.py file:

```
# start new section 
from django.conf import settings  
if settings.DEBUG:  
    if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'):  
        import debugpy         
        debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 3000))         
        print('Attached!') 
# end new section
```

However, when this code block is present, my custom system checks are completely ignored. If I comment out or remove this code and save the file, the system checks are triggered successfully. I'm unsure why this issue is occurring. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem where custom system checks were being ignored?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.